# How to print online (not local or within network) pdf file using acrobat.exe

Tags: c#, pdf, acrobat

I am trying to print online pdf document using command line as below.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 2015\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"  /t "http://example.com/file1.pdf#fdf=http://example.com/data1.fdf" "\\PrinterName" "" ""
```

It says File name, Volume name or directory is incorrect. Is there any way that I can print without copying pdf file locally?

Answer (score -1):

can you create a batch command?

create a batch command, something like "AcroPrnt.bat"  (or "AcroPrnt.cmd")

inside the batch command:

```
  wget (or curl) %1 (the file to download and print) > tempAcro.pdf
  wget (or curl) %2 (the fdf file)
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 2015\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe"  /t tempAcro.pdf#fdf=%2 "\\PrinterName" "" "" 
  del tempAcro.pdf
```

and then print a document from the internet using

```
AcroPrnt "http://example.com/file1.pdf" "http://example.com/data1.fdf"
```

this code will not work unless you download curl or wget, and we need to modify the script accordingly.

gathered info from http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf

Comment: So I have to store tempAcro.pdf somewhere locally, right?

Comment: In this case I need to give folder write permission to logged in user. I'm not sure whether I can do that unless there is no other option.

Comment: when the user logs in,can they write to their desktop?